# StartTime and EndTime params ignored in Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration (Exchange 2013)

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013

I'm using the following command:

```
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity “First Last” -AutoReplyState enabled -StartTime '3/3/2014 00:00:00' -EndTime '3/8/2014 00:00:00' -InternalMessage $ooomessage -ExternalMessage $ooomessage
```

($ooomessage is set in another command.)

The problem is that the start time always begins at the beginning of the current hour and the end time is always 24 hours later.

According to `Get-Help` I am using the correct format. I've tried adding leading zeros and also using AM/PM format but it's made no difference. I don't get any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `-AutoReplyState Scheduled` instead.

The doc says :

> *StartTime*
>   (...) To use this parameter, the AutoReplyState parameter must be set to Scheduled.
>
> *EndTime*
>   (...) To use this parameter, the AutoReplyState parameter must be set to Scheduled.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638217.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I was too focused on the syntax that I failed to actually read the docs. RTFM...